# jQuery UI sortable with fixed rows

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-selectors, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using a jQuery UI sortable with a table (works fine).  I would like to make the header and last row fixed (non-moveable).

The jQuery UI docs indicate this can be done using a selector for items, but I am at a loss for the syntax.

Here is the relevant code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
    $("#response_options tbody.content").sortable();
    $("#response_options tbody.content").disableSelection();
});
</script>

<table id="response_options" class="data-table">
    <tbody class="content">
        <tr>
            <th>Links</th><th>Response</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="sortable-row">
           <td>Edit</td>
           <td>Item 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="sortable-row">
            <td>Edit</td>
            <td>Item 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="sortable-row">
            <td>Edit</td>
            <td>Item 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="sortable-row">
            <td>Edit</td>
            <td>Item 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="sortable-row">
            <td>Edit</td>
            <td>Item 5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Edit</td>
            <td>Item 1</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The selector goes inside .sortable(...):

```
$("#response_options tbody.content").sortable();
```

as

```
$("#response_options tbody.content").sortable( items: ??? );
```

and it should be possible to select only items with class="sortable-row"; but again, I am at a loss for the syntax.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should work:

```
$("#response_options tbody.content").sortable({items: 'tr.sortable-row'});
```

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me:

```
        jQuery(".sortable tbody").sortable({
            items: 'tr:not(:first)'
        });
```

Answer (score 4):

For this markup:

```
<table id="tableid">
    <thead>
        <tr>    
            <th>namr</th>
            <th>id</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>jagadeesh</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>jagadeesh</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Use this jQuery:

```
$('#tableid tbody').sortable();
```

It will move only body content of table you cannot move header part.